# Git - Modify an old commit with the file currently in my working directory

Tags: git, git-rebase

So I've committed a file that was wrong, it is not my last commit (it is `HEAD~9`). And I wanted to replace that file with the version I currently have in my working directory.

I was going to do a rebase interactive but I realised I need to clean first my working directory which has the file with I want to replace the old version in `HEAD~9`.

There are similar questions but didn't find an answer that addresses this scenario. Which is the way to proceed in this case?

Comment: Trying to understand the problem, why do you need to change the file *in its history* rather than just commiting it at the tip of your branch?

Comment: Yes, I guess _I could_, but I didn't want to commit that file version to begin with, because it was WIP. So, if I checkout a commit between _that_ commit and its fix, 10 commits after, to test something, it would probably crash or work unexpectedly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like an [interactive](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) [rebase](https://billtheconqueror.com/2018/07/14/commit-early-commit-often-the-interactive-rebase-squash-and-fixup/) would give you what you want.  You would first need to commit the file in a "temporary" commit.  Then through the interactive rebase you can `fixup` `HEAD~9`.

1. `git add <file>`
2. `git commit -m 'fixup commit'`
3. `git rebase -i HEAD~10`
4. In the editor move fixup commit directly after `HEAD~9` and set it to `f` for `fixup`.
5. Save and close the editor

A `fixup` is a `squash` but retains the commit message of the commit being squashed into.  If any of the commits between `HEAD` and `HEAD~9` also modify that file, then you may get merge conflicts when the commits are replayed.

Comment: Just for the record, as commits in interactive rebase are processed from top to down, when you said before `HEAD~9` you meant right after the commit you want to _fix up_.

Comment: @40detectives, yes good clarification.  From top to bottom, the `fixup` commit should be directly below the `HEAD~9` commit in the text editor during the rebase.